# Why private variables in an anonymous function are accessible from outside the function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

After reading a piece of "Essential JS Design Patterns" book, I can't understand the behavior of private variables in this code:

```
var SingletonTester = (function () {

  // options: an object containing configuration options for the singleton
  // e.g var options = { name: "test", pointX: 5};
  function Singleton( options )  {

    // set options to the options supplied
    // or an empty object if none are provided
    options = options || {};

    // set some properties for our singleton
    this.name = "SingletonTester";

    this.pointX = options.pointX || 6;

    this.pointY = options.pointY || 10;

  }

  // our instance holder
  var instance;

  // an emulation of static variables and methods
  var _static  = {

    name:  "SingletonTester",

    // Method for getting an instance. It returns
    // a singleton instance of a singleton object
    getInstance:  function( options ) {
      if( instance  ===  undefined )  {
        instance = new Singleton( options );
      }

      return  instance;

    }
  };

  return  _static;

})();

var singletonTest  =  SingletonTester.getInstance({
  pointX:  5
});

// Log the output of pointX just to verify it is correct
// Outputs: 5
console.log( singletonTest.pointX );
```

This is an example given by the book about the Singleton pattern.
There is a anonymous function, which return an object containing the "name" member and the "getInstance" method for returning the instance of "Singleton" function.
My troumble is understand how the object stored in SingletonTester can access to the "instance" private var. I mean, after the anonymous function has done its job, the SingletonTester variable should hold only the object:

```
{
    name:  "SingletonTester",

    // Method for getting an instance. It returns
    // a singleton instance of a singleton object
    getInstance:  function( options ) {
      if( instance  ===  undefined )  {
        instance = new Singleton( options );
 }
```

and this object does not know what instance is. Same thing for the instantiation of "Singleton" function. How does it know what function is "Singleton", which was defined in the scope of the anonymous function?

Comment: Looks like just variable scope, `instance` is defined higher than `getInstance()` inside the class function, so it's available in any scope below it, but not above it, so it's available inside `getInstance()` but not outside the IIFE, unless `getInstance()` is called as it exposes the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're experiencing is lexical scoping in JavaScript. Basically, whenever you execute a function, you have access to that function's scope. In addition to that though, you also have access to the lexical scope in which the function was defined.

Let's take a look at an example:

```
var someObject = (function () {
  var privateVariable = 18;

  var getValue = function () {
    return privateVariable;
  };

  return {
    getValue: getValue
  };
})();
```

The object 'someObject' has a method 'getValue' which when executed returns the value 18. But how is this possible? Here's how the JavaScript engine works when you try executing someObject.getValue():

1. The JavaScript engine performs a property lookup on the someObject object and sees that it has its own getValue property.
2. Once it's located the function object (getValue), it executes the function.
3. When the function gets executed, the JavaScript engine tries to lookup the value for privateVariable.
4. However, within the scope of the 'getValue' function, privateVariable doesn't exist.
5. Therefore, the JavaScript engine looks to the PARENT scope (i.e. the scope in which the getValue function was declared).
6. This scope corresponds to the scope from the anonymous function. And within this scope, privateVariable has a value of 18.

That's lexical scoping in JavaScript. Regarding your example, this is why the instance of SingletonTester has access to the "instance" variable.

I HIGHLY recommend this book to learn more: [Scope and Closures](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/README.md#you-dont-know-js-scope--closures)

Comment: Thank you very much! I started programming with javascript only recently and there are a lot of things very strange for me, coming from PHP. Nice answer.

Comment: Glad that I could help. If you feel up for it, the link I provided is a great resource to really understand how scoping works. In fact, its not just for JavaScript because many programming languages utilize lexical scoping as well.